# How to show the day with the lowest spread in temp lowest

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Working through a problem as a new programmer.  The question is In weather.csv you’ll find daily weather data. Write a program to read the file, then output the day number (column one) with the smallest temperature spread (the maximum temperature is the second column, the minimum the third column).

I made the list public here for the weather.csv file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMxCY_CdpdhDjMZZWGzyh-whEvZYxH2XiBfA4AfqZJw/edit#gid=0

I have tried to sort my list, I have tried to print min(day_spread), which returns "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".  I am completely lost as to where to go with my code from here.  Thanks!

edit: I have added tot_spread and made day an int.

```
import csv


with open("weather.csv", 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        day = int(row[0])
        max_weather = int(row[1])
        min_weather = int(row[2])
        day_spread = (max_weather - min_weather)
        tot_spread = [day, day_spread]
        print(min(tot_spread)
```

Comment: You're almost there. The thing is, `day_spread` is only a single number, but `min()` takes a list as input and gives you the minimum value from that list.

Comment: That makes sense,  I added this

        tot_spread = [day, day_spread]
        print(min(tot_spread))

But now it prints out all the days, so, I don't think I made it a list, if I am correct?  It is 4 separate lists?  I also changed day to be an int

Comment: Ok, I meant to hint at `reader` being an iterable (almost a list). This is the right direction, but let me post an answer (I don't wanna cause more confusion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go the route with `min`, but you still need to make a list of
all your day/spread pairs, and then return the minimum value from that list.

```py
import csv

spreads = [] # list for all values

with open("weather.csv", 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        day = int(row[0])
        max_weather = int(row[1])
        min_weather = int(row[2])
        day_spread = (max_weather - min_weather)
        tot_spread = [day, day_spread]
        spreads.append(tot_spread) # add the pair to the list

# print the minimum
print(min(spreads, key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

The `key=lambda x:x[1]` tells `min` to return the minimum based on the second value of each pair, the spread.

As an alternative, you could store a current minimum, and for each iteration,
check if the new value is lower than the current one. If you don't know about `lambda` etc. yet, this might be easier to follow:

```py
import csv

min_spread = 99999 # some ridiculously high value
min_day = -1 # doesn't really matter what value

with open("weather.csv", 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        day = int(row[0])
        max_weather = int(row[1])
        min_weather = int(row[2])
        day_spread = (max_weather - min_weather)

        # if the new value is lower than the current minimum,
        # take it as the new minimum
        if day_spread < min_spread:
            min_spread = day_spread
            min_day = day

# print the minimum
print(min_day)
```

Comment: The 2nd option is definitely easier for me to follow as I have not learned lambda yet, but now I have something new to learn.  Thank you so much for the help!